# Number of arrivals distribution, Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, queueing-theory, poisson-process

Suppose that arrivals occur at $T_1, T_2, \ldots$ . The interval times $A_n = T_n - T_{n-1}$ are i.i.d. $\exp(\lambda)$, where $T_0 =0$. Let $N(t)$ denote the number of arrivals in $[0,t]$ and define for $n \geq 0$
\begin{align}
p_n(t) = \mathbb{P}(N(t)=n), \qquad t>0.
\end{align}
It could be shown that for $n \geq 1$
\begin{align}
p_n(t) = \int_0^t p_{n-1}(t-x) \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ dx, \qquad t>0. \qquad (*)
\end{align}
In order to find the distribution of $p_n$, I want to solve this integral equation. I am aware of the fact that $p_n$ satisfies the following differential equation
\begin{align}
p_n'(t) = -\lambda p_n(t) + \lambda p_{n-1}(t), \qquad t>0,
\end{align}
with initial condition $p_n(0)=0$. Even considering implementing the above expression in $(*)$, I do not see how to solve the integral. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume that you allready *know* what you heading for: $p_n(t)=e^{-t\lambda}\frac{(t\lambda)^n}{n!}$. So use induction to solve $(*)$.

Comment: Your differential-difference equation reduces into a standard ODE for $n=0$. (What ought $p_{-1}(t)$ be?) Solve that. Then apply induction.

Comment: Okido, thanks for your suggestions.